# How to make @ConditionalOnMissingBean work by behavior of dynamic create spring bean (eg: beanfactory register)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am writing a spring boot starter, I want to implement dynamic creation of bean injection into spring ioc, and can make @ConditionalOnMissingBean take effect without creating default bean.

I tried to weave the beanfactory directly in the configuration class and dynamically create the bean by calling the registerSingleton method via the ConfigurableBeanFactory, but the result is wrong, @ConditionalOnMissingBean does not take effect. @Bean is ok, this should be related to the spring boot scan @Configuration class and the corresponding @Bean method, but @Bean can not achieve dynamic creation of the bean, because the bean I need is generated according to the content of the configuration file, the number Uncertain, the content is uncertain.

```java
@Override
public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    ConfigurableBeanFactory configurableBeanFactory = (ConfigurableBeanFactory) beanFactory;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    // Generate a bean based on the configuration
    ...
    SpringBean bean = ...
    configurableBeanFactory.registerSingleton(SpringBeanName, bean);
}
```

I hope that @ConditionalOnMissingBean will still take effect if the bean is dynamically created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As its stated in the [API documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html?is-external=true):

> The @Conditional annotation may be used in any of the following ways:
>
> - as a type-level annotation on any class directly or indirectly annotated with @Component, including @Configuration classes
> - as a meta-annotation, for the purpose of composing custom stereotype annotations
> - as a method-level annotation on any @Bean method

That means it won't have an effect on dynamically created beans that registers in the `ApplicationContext` after the start up.
So when you want to achieve a similar kind of behavior try checking if a bean is present in the ApplicationContext like that:

```java
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;

...
context.getBeansOfType(YourType.class).isEmpty()
```

#### Update:

When you want to get rid of the default configuration of that bean you need to exclude it. There are two ways to achieve that. Either by excluding the whole configuration file where the bean is defined by specifying it like `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SomeConfig.class)` or by implementing your own exclude filter on [@ComponentScan](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#excludeFilters--).

Comment: This is a good idea, but the @Conditional* decision is in a public jar and cannot be customized by me.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will refer to your suggestion.

Comment: When it solves your problem, please accept the answer to mark it for others that find this question.